# Django: Offcanvas pdf preview iteration issue

Tags: python, html, django, pdf

**Hy guys**

i'm setting up a page where there is a table which contains some meta data about a pdf file.

Ofcourse for user friendliness i want to give the user a preview of a stored file and i'd like to do that in an off-canvas.

**my html file**

```
 <h5>Add a document </h5>
  <div class="addition">
    <form method="POST" action="" enctype='multipart/form-data' autocomplete="off">
      {% csrf_token %}                


        <div>

            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="name" name="name" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off">
          </div>
          <div>
              <label for="myfile">Select a file:</label>
            <input type="file" id="myfile" name="pdf">
          </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Submit</button>
           </div>
         </form>
        </div>




       <h4>Overview documents</h4>
       <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Descritpion</th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for item in all_pdfs %}   
            <tr>                    
            <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                <td><a href="{{item.pdf.url}}">{{ item.name }}</a></td>
                <td>
              <div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasRight" aria-controls="offcanvasRight">Toggle right offcanvas</button>

                        <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasRight" aria-labelledby="offcanvasRightLabel">
                          <div class="offcanvas-header">
                            <h5 id="offcanvasRightLabel">Offcanvas right</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
                          </div>
                          <div class="offcanvas-body">
                             <embed src="{{ item.pdf.url }}" type="application/pdf" height="700px" width="350">
                          </div>
                        </div>
              </div>
                </td>
          </tr>

            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This html page contains 2 sections: the actual form and below the table that represents all the records in my database

**models.py**

```
class TestPDF(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='test')
```

**views.py**

```
def test(request):
all_pdfs = TestPDF.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        settings_form = TestPDFForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

        if settings_form.is_valid():
            settings_form.save()

        return render(request, 'test.html', {"all_pdfs": all_pdfs})
    else:
        return render(request, 'test.html', {"all_pdfs": all_pdfs})
return render(request, 'test.html', {"all_pdfs": all_pdfs})
```

and finally my

**forms.py**

```
class TestPDFForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = TestPDF
    fields = ['name', 'pdf']
```

**Normal Behavior**
I want to click on a random button and see the corresponding pdf document in an offcanvas

**Problem:**
When i click the button on anything i get the wrong preview in my offcanvas. I always get the first pdf while the link that is in the table correctly corresponds to the correct PDF.
So for some reason the offcanvas doesn't correctly iterates in that last table. This issue has bugging me out for quite a while and I can't find any solution yet.

Thanks a lot for the ideas!

Comment: `id="offcanvasRight"` you are writing this in a **loop**. An id is supposed to be **unique**. (Most likely this is the issue, I don't see your javascript but most likely it tries to select the element with the id pointed by `data-bs-target` and given that there are multiple of the same id only the first one gets selected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id attribute is supposed to be unique in the html document. Refer [https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/...](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute):

> The id attribute specifies its element's **unique identifier (ID)**.
> The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home
> subtree and must contain at least one character.

What should we do when we need multiple id's in a loop? Use `forloop.counter` (Reference [`for` template tag [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for)) to make unique id's.

```
{% for item in all_pdfs %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td><a href="{{item.pdf.url}}">{{ item.name }}</a></td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasRight-{{ forloop.counter }}" aria-controls="offcanvasRight">Toggle right offcanvas</button>
                <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasRight-{{ forloop.counter }}" aria-labelledby="offcanvasRightLabel-{{ forloop.counter }}">
                    <div class="offcanvas-header">
                        <h5 id="offcanvasRightLabel-{{ forloop.counter }}">Offcanvas right</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="offcanvas-body">
                        <embed src="{{ item.pdf.url }}" type="application/pdf" height="700px" width="350"> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yeah I first thought about your first comment, because it wasn't fully clear to me what you meant ( i thought that those id's are more for binding the html elements) and i indeed fixed it with `offcanvasRight{{ item.id }}` I think this solution is a bit more soundproof as it is my pk?

Comment: @Gerhand `offcanvasRight{{ item.id }}` would indeed also work. I used `forloop.counter` with the consideration that one might not want people to find out the database ids of the relevant objects.

Comment: that is indeed true. I might have to figure something out for that. But in terms of when multiple authenticated users are online is the system not going to maybe be buggy because multiple people can have the same forloop number?

Comment: @Gerhand no need to be concerned about that. JavaScript is client side meaning it runs on the clients machine. So when they click the button the script only runs for them and on their machine, not on others machines.

Comment: a ok thanks, then i might swith to your solution entirely